# PHP/MYSQL: Update Query where value is missing from WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I think I know the answer to this but want to get confirmation.

If you have a simple update query with a where clause and the value of the variable in the where clause is missing, does that mean every record gets updated?

```
//let's say $name is empty

UPDATE users SET name= 'Jason' WHERE userid = '$name'

is that the same as 

UPDATE users SET name= 'Jason' WHERE userid = ''
```

Is the behavior that every record would get updated?

And, if so, is there anything you can put in the SQL to prevent this potential catastrophe?

Thanks for guidance.

Comment: Then it will set those values only which satisfies the condition.

Comment: it will execute but no rows will be affected. . . . .

Comment: Its updated only those records which have userid is empty or not set any value means null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both queries will update all records where `userid` column is empty. But it doesn't means that rows with `userid` value which is equal to `NULL` will be affected. If you want to use `WHERE` against `NULL` column, read [how to working with NULL values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html).

Comment: So you are saying it will only update rows where the column is empty and not all rows in the database?

Comment: I said that it will update all records **only if** these records has empty `userid` column.

Comment: Is there a way in the SQL (as opposed to php) to prevent updates if the userid value is empty or null?

Comment: Yes, use primary key, foreign key (with constraints) and you will not have any issues with your data relations. Just use the power of RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is empty, or without a value, or "", and on your table there is no record where `userid` is empty or null, then no record will be updated as the where-condition would favor no record, however if there is any record with empty `userid`, then the record will be updated with the values you provided to the respective columns.